# Connection timeout example

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Is there any example where I can see how connection timeout error get throws ?**

I tried to put a a select query where it select like 50 000 rows and insert it in a `GridView`. 
I set the connection string, open the connection and set `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)`.
I set the IIS Connection Timeout to be 60 sec, but it's not working and not throwing the error.
I am using Sql Server

Comment: Which database software?

Comment: i am using sql server as a database software

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, use the [waitfor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) command:

```
waitfor delay '01:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Connection Timeout` that you can set in the connection string is used to determine how long the client will wait for the connection to be *initialized* (for lack of a better word). It does not control how long the client will wait for the results of a database operation.

In order to set **that** timeout, you can do it using the `CommandTimeout` property on a `SqlCommand`:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("testTimeout", conn))
{
    // next line is where the Connection Timeout will take 
    // effect if the connection cannot be opened in time
    conn.Open();
    comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.CommandTimeout = 60;
    // next line is where the Command Timeout takes effect
    // if the operation takes a long time to complete
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

To test the command timeout, create the "testTimeout" stored procedure and have it delay (see answer from **Blorgbeard**) for longer then the command timeout used. The default value for the command timeout is 30 (=30 seconds). See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).